# How to write characters containing the ǚ pinyin symbol in most common Chinese Input Methods?

Tags: pinyin

I am using four different input methods for typing 汉字. Most of them share the same principles for translating what you type in pinyin to Chinese characters. But I am unable to figure out how to type in pinyin words with an *U with Umlaut* like **ǚ**, for example **女**.

I am using: [Google Pinyin Input](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.inputmethod.pinyin&hl=en) in Android, and [Chinese Sun Pinyin](https://github.com/sunpinyin/sunpinyin), [ibus m17n](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ibus-m17n) and [ibus-pinyin](https://github.com/phuang/ibus-pinyin) in Ubuntu

Is there some common way used to type it?

Comment: sometimes, like in google translate, use v instead. so "nv" = 女.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As pinyin doesn't use the letter **v**, then words containing the **u with umlaut** can be written with `v` key, then combined with the number keys to get different tones.

For example:

- v+1 = ǖ
- v+2 = ǘ
- v+3 = ǚ
- v+4 = ǜ
- v+5 = ü

Comment: Perfect: I struggled so much to type 女儿 = nv er!